# Parsing a "" character to the data of a Reg Add command?

Tags: batch-file

I am really struggling with this

I want to create a reg add command that replace the (Default) value in a specific key with an expanded string value that contains the following data:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen %1
```

My command works if I use this:

```
Reg Add "HKCR\Paint.Picture\shell\open\command" /VE /T REG_EXPAND_SZ /D "TEST" /F
```

But as soon as I change "TEST" to the above value the command fails for incorrect syntax. Is anyone able to help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, single line batch file command, *(remembering that it must be run as administrator)*:

```bat
@"%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Add "HKCR\Paint.Picture\shell\open\command" /VE /T REG_EXPAND_SZ /D "%%SystemRoot%%\System32\rundll32.exe \"%%ProgramFiles%%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll\", ImageView_Fullscreen %%1" /F
```

Comment: Works great! I am in your debt sir.

Comment: One follow up question, if you don't mind... I suspect this is a windows thing not anything to do with reg.exe or the command you gave me, but after running this and I go to the registry location, the first bit is changed to %C:\Windows% in the path rather than staying as %systemroot% like I want it to. Don't suppose you know why that might be?

Comment: You should only get that sort of output if you ran the command from the Command Prompt. Your question used the [batch-file] tag, and my answer specifically stated batch file. BTW, if the answer solves your issue, please click on the large check mark to its left to mark it as accepted. Please also note also that as your question involved the correct escaping of the percent characters it was not a duplicate of the answers noted in the close notification.